# How do you test/troubleshoot hiera in a Puppet environment

Tags: puppet, hiera, puppet-foreman

I'm using Puppet alongside Foreman to provision hosts, and I've currently got all of Puppet config as modules in a repository. I'd like to use Hiera but I've never been able to get even the simplest thing to pull from one of the `.yaml` files that I add. My master `puppet.conf` is:

```
[main]
    basemodulepath = /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/common:/etc/puppetlabs/code/modules:/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/modules:/usr/share/puppet/modules
    codedir = /etc/puppetlabs/code
    environmentpath = /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments
    hiera_config = /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/hiera.yaml
    hostprivkey = $privatekeydir/$certname.pem { mode = 640 }
    logdir = /var/log/puppetlabs/puppet
    pluginfactsource = puppet:///pluginfacts
    pluginsource = puppet:///plugins
    privatekeydir = $ssldir/private_keys { group = service }
    reports = foreman
    rundir = /var/run/puppetlabs
    server = foreman.domain.net
    show_diff = false
    ssldir = /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl
    vardir = /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache

[agent]
    certname = foreman.domain.net
    classfile = $statedir/classes.txt
    default_schedules = false
    environment = production
    listen = false
    localconfig = $vardir/localconfig
    masterport = 8140
    noop = false
    pluginsync = true
    report = true
    runinterval = 1800
    splay = false
    splaylimit = 1800
    usecacheonfailure = true

[master]
    autosign = /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/autosign.conf { mode = 0664 }
    ca = true
    certname = foreman.domain.net
    external_nodes = /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/node.rb
    logdir = /var/log/puppetlabs/puppetserver
    node_terminus = exec
    parser = current
    rundir = /var/run/puppetlabs/puppetserver
    ssldir = /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl
    strict_variables = false
    vardir = /opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver
```

contents of `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/hiera.yaml`:

```
---
version: 5
defaults:
  datadir: hieradata
  data_hash: yaml_data
hierarchy:
  - name: "Per-node data"
    path: "nodes/%{trusted.certname}.yaml"
  - name: "Per-domain data"
    path: "domains/%{facts.networking.domain}.yaml"
  - name: "OS family"
    path: "os/%{facts.os.family}.yaml"
  - name: "Other hierarchy levels"
    path: "common.yaml"
```

and structure of `hieradata`:

```
hieradata/
├── common.yaml
├── domains
│   └── domain.net.yaml
├── nodes
│   ├── foreman.domain.net.yaml
│   └── test.domain.net.yaml
└── os
    └── Debian.yaml
```

and for example the foreman specific data file content:

```
---
environment: production
classes:
  - roles::default
```

finally, versions of things that seem relevant:

```
$ puppet --version
5.5.3
$ facter --version
3.11.3 (commit 1854ababc68ec12ca40bdc143e46c3d5434b92ba)
$ hiera --version
3.4.3
```

I feel like I've followed along with the various guides on the internets, but none of my hosts seem to use the settings in the `.yaml` files. How do you test `hiera`? I would expect that there'd be some sensible way to resolve what files are applied to an individual node, but I can't find a command that works to do that, or even search for some of the classes that I've created in my environments. I would also think that I'd be able to use something like `hiera -c hiera.yaml --hash profiles`, but that gives an error about v5 syntax.

Comment: It looks like you can use `puppet lookup --node test.domain.net --explain classes` to resolve `hiera` information. This works for me on the master, but on the agent side it's pulling local information and not what it should receive from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer to the question is actually what I put in the comment that I made.

`puppet lookup --node test.domain.net --explain classes`

Executing that command on the server showed that it was supposed to work. My real problem was that my site manifest for the node didn't include `hiera_include('classes')`, which I got to because of the lookup.